# Sumar o restar la diferencia de tiempo entre dos fechas en java

Tags: java, sql

Necesito sumar o restar la diferencia de tiempo entre las fechas, 
Si el `ESTADOLINEA` es 1 sumar, y si el `ESTADOLINEA` es 2, restar el tiempo.

Esta es la tabla SQL:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi idea es hacer un bucle para recorrer los registros

Este es mi código:

```
private void fisico(ResultSet rs) {
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            if (rs.getRow() != 0) {
                //si es 2 la maquina esta parada, si NO la maquina esta MARCHA 
                if (rs.getInt(2) == 2) {
                    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " Maquina parada " + rs.getInt(2));
                    fechaInicio = String.valueOf(rs.getTimestamp(4));
                } else {
                    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " Maquina en marcha " + rs.getInt(2));
                }
            } else {
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("" + ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ver todos los métodos disponibles para la Clase `Timestamp` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html

Para hacer operaciones entre fechas lo mas fácil, sea el lenguaje que sea es obtener la representación en UNIX (milisegundos) y luego, realizar las operaciones.

Si quieres obtener la fecha actual (del sistema) en milisegundos tendrás que hacer esto:

```
(int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
```

Para obtener los milisegundos a partir de un timestamp tienes que usar el siguiente método:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#getTime()

Answer (score 0):

puedes pedir el dato ya procesado desde la bd

```
  SELECT if ( estado = 1, (unix_timestamp(fecha1)-unix_timestamp( sysdate() ), unix_timestamp(fecha1)+unix_timestamp( sysdate() ) ) as diferencia FROM tabla
```

y puedes filtra ( si quieres ) ahí mismo

```
WHERE diferencia > 3600
```

por ejempo